# How to Fine-Tune Multilingual Translational Transformer Models

Tags: nlp, pytorch, transformer, machine-translation

I'm trying to fine-tune facebook/nllb-200-distteled-600M model on my english to arabic dataset, but the results are so bad I'm expecting there should be something wrong with defining the model and tokenizer, or maybe preprocessing the data. My code the following:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

import pandas as pd

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M")


model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M")

dff = pd.read_csv('/content/data.csv')



"""


# Formatting Data


"""

source = dff['eng_Latn'].values.tolist()
target = dff['arb_Arab'].values.tolist()


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
max = 512
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(source, target, test_size=0.2)
X_train_tokenized = tokenizer(X_train, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=max, return_tensors="pt")
y_train_tokenized = tokenizer(y_train, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=max, return_tensors="pt")
X_val_tokenized = tokenizer(X_val, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=max, return_tensors="pt")
y_val_tokenized = tokenizer(y_val, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=max, return_tensors="pt")

import torch
class ForDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, inputs, targets):
        self.inputs = inputs
        self.targets = targets
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.targets)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        input_ids = torch.tensor(self.inputs["input_ids"][index]).squeeze()
        target_ids = torch.tensor(self.targets["input_ids"][index]).squeeze()
        
        return {"input_ids": input_ids, "labels": target_ids}

train_dataset = ForDataset(X_train_tokenized, y_train_tokenized)
test_dataset = ForDataset(X_val_tokenized, y_val_tokenized)


from transformers import DataCollatorForSeq2Seq

data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer=tokenizer, model=model, return_tensors="pt")

"""# Metrics"""

import evaluate

metric = evaluate.load("sacrebleu")

import numpy as np


def postprocess_text(preds, labels):
    preds = [pred.strip() for pred in preds]
    labels = [[label.strip()] for label in labels]

    return preds, labels


def compute_metrics(eval_preds):
    preds, labels = eval_preds
    if isinstance(preds, tuple):
        preds = preds[0]
    decoded_preds = tokenizer.batch_decode(preds, skip_special_tokens=True)

    labels = np.where(labels != -100, labels, tokenizer.pad_token_id)
    decoded_labels = tokenizer.batch_decode(labels, skip_special_tokens=True)

    decoded_preds, decoded_labels = postprocess_text(decoded_preds, decoded_labels)

    result = metric.compute(predictions=decoded_preds, references=decoded_labels)
    result = {"bleu": result["score"]}

    prediction_lens = [np.count_nonzero(pred != tokenizer.pad_token_id) for pred in preds]
    result["gen_len"] = np.mean(prediction_lens)
    result = {k: round(v, 4) for k, v in result.items()}
    return result

"""# Training"""

from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, Seq2SeqTrainer



training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(

    output_dir="mymodel",

    evaluation_strategy="epoch",

    save_strategy = 'epoch',

    learning_rate=2e-5,

    per_device_train_batch_size=16,

    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,

    weight_decay=0.01,

    save_total_limit=3,

    num_train_epochs=20,

    predict_with_generate=True,

    load_best_model_at_end=True

)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(

    model=model,

    args=training_args,

    train_dataset=train_dataset,

    eval_dataset=test_dataset,

    tokenizer=tokenizer,

    data_collator=data_collator,

    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,

)

trainer.train()

""" # Testing """

trainer.save_model('finalmodel')

from transformers import pipeline

mymodel = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("./finalmodel")

translator = pipeline ('translation' , model = mymodel, tokenizer=tokenizer, src_lang = 'eng_Latn', tgt_lang= 'arb_Arab')

print (translator('suddenly, we were attacked '))
```

I previously trained the helsinki model using huggingface autotrain tool on smaller data and I got better results. is it the data or the training process?
Does the tokenizer and model know which language I'm using based on the columns names, or do I need to define that?

P.S. I'm new to NLP, so, much of my code is copied.